# recognize detect RSS feed using PHP

Tags: php, rss

what is the best way to detect whether a given url is actually an RSS feed?

Comment: i just came up with an idea, to check how many title tags are in it.. cause if you got more than 3 its definitely RSS?!

Answer (score 3):

It's tough to do reliably if the URLs you need to check are arbitrary.

One thing would be the `content-type` it serves. That can change, though, because (IIRC) IE needs `text/xml` to display an actual feed, and not to offer to download it. For more on the issue see [here](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/381.cfm).

The second (and more reliable) thing would be to analyze the file's structure. Some ideas are here: [**How to detect if a page is an RSS or ATOM feed**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442984/how-to-detect-if-a-page-is-an-rss-or-atom-feed)

The simplest way could be, as Pascal Martin recommends in that question, opening an URL with the Zend RSS reader. If that works out, it's a valid RSS resource, otherwise, it's not.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a python developer this is quite easy. I faced the same situation a while ago.
First install the libray "feedparser" on your system as a python library

For example your feed link is =  "www.example.org/feed"
chk the following

```
    import feedparser
    f=feedparser.parse("www.example.org/feed")
    if len(f.version)>0:
        print "It is a feed with version",str(f.version)   #Since the parsing is done and versions are allocated only to actual valid feeds otherwise an empty string is there 
    else:
        print "Not a Valid Feed Url"
```